# Simon's algorithm example

Tags: simons-algorithm

I am trying to wrap my head around Simon's algorithm and I am trying to solve a question.

[image]

This is the solution that I have come up with. Please correct me if I am wrong.
[image]

Comment: You could solve it just by checking all 4 possible values for $a: 00, 01, 10, 11$. If you want to use quantum algorithm you can follow this answer https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1718/5870

Comment: please avoid using images of text whenever possible, just type their content using mathjax

Comment: I got it. Thank you.